# Converting nested JSON to clear pd dataframe

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, nested

I've got a JSON file that I want to convert to a useful `pd.DataFrame` so that I can use this for further modelling. The JSON file looks like this:

```
json_file = {
  "x1": [
    {
      "a": "XZ12ABC1834",
      "b": "J. Doe",
      "c": [
        {
          "Amount": -50,
          "Date": "2021-08-15T10:00:00.000Z",
          "CategoryId": "abc123",
          "CounterParty": "The Farm",
          "Description": "some description",
          "Counter": "XYZ456AZ",
          "Type": "bc"
        },{
          "Amount": -1,
          "Date": "2020-08-15T10:00:00.000Z",
          "CategoryId": "cde123",
          "CounterParty": "The pool",
          "Description": "some other description",
          "Counter": "WYZ12",
          "Type": "X"
        }
         ]
      "a": "XX34XX872",
      "b": "J. Doe",
      "c": [
        {
          "Amount": -1,50,
          "Date": "2019-05-15T10:00:00.000Z",
          "CategoryId": "QWR627",
          "CounterParty": "The City",
          "Description": "last other description",
          "Counter": "QWE123",
          "Type": "S"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to convert this JSON file to a dataframe that somewhat looks like this:

| var1 | a | b | amount | date | CategoryID | Counterparty | Description | Counter | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | XZ12ABC1834 | J. Doe | -50 | 2021-08-15T10:00:00.000Z | abc123 | The Farm | some description | XYZ456AZ | bv |
| x1 | XZ12ABC1834 | J. Doe | -1 | 2020-08-15T10:00:00.000Z | cde123 | The pool | some other description | WYZZ12 | X |
| x1 | XX34XX872 | J. Doe | -1.50 | 2019-05-15T10:00:00.000Z | cde123 | The city | last other description | QWE123 | S |

Hopefully this is enough info for someone to help me with this matter.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.json_normalize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

result = []

for key in json_file:
  df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(
    json_file[key], 
    record_path =['c'], 
    meta=['a', 'b']
  )
  df_nested_list['var1'] = key
  result.append(df_nested_list)
pd.concat(result)
```

For more information look at: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-convert-json-into-a-pandas-dataframe-100b2ae1e0d8

Comment: Why do you only take the first element of `json_file['x1']`? All should be taken into consideration according to OP's example. Also you might consider putting this in a loop since OP probably has other x-lists in their dictionary

Comment: @DataDude Do you have more than one category for `var1`?

Comment: @Tranbi just drafted the basic idea, you can edit